# React Native fetch https Node js server

Tags: node.js, react-native, types, https, openssl

i seriously need help with this:

i built my first node js server, here:

```
var express = require('express'),
app = express(),
https = require('https');
port = process.env.PORT || 443,
mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Task = require('./api/models/myCarModel'), 
bodyParser = require('body-parser');
fs = require("fs");

const options = {
key: fs.readFileSync('./static/HttpsFile/privatekey.pem').toString(),
cert: fs.readFileSync('./static/HttpsFile/certificate.pem').toString(),

};


mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/Tododb'); 


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var routes = require('./api/routes/myCarRoutes'); //importing route
routes(app); //register the route

https.createServer(options, app).listen(port);

console.log(options.key)
console.log('RESTful API server started on: ' + port);
```

and here's my simple react-native app home:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Button, StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, View } from 'react-native';

const Home = () => {

const [text, setText] = useState('');

useEffect(()=> {
    debugger
    fetch('https://192.168.1.8:443/cars', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }})
        //axios.get("https://192.168.1.8:3000/cars")
        .then((res:any) => {
        debugger;
    }, (err:any) => {
        console.log(err)
        debugger;
    })

}, [])

 return(...etc...)
```

now:
when I first used postman to test the API I got an error regarding the use of self-signed certificates ( which I'm using through OpneSSL ). I kindly asked Postman to accept the idea, and everything went on fine.
This is not the case with react-native:
I'm using expo, testing my app on my android phone and when I debug the API call I get the following error in the error-then: "TypeError: Network request failed".

I don't want to dirty solve the problem by making Android accept HTTP protocol.

Ty everyone

Answer (score 1):

So you are running the app on your phone? Your phone does not have access to the server you are running on your computer. 'https://192.168.1.8:443/cars' is only accessible if you try to connect to it on the same device (it could be a simulator running on your computer). But still this may not work if you use an internal device. In that case you can access it trough http://10.0.2.2:433 (this worked for me).

Bonus point: Https does not work on local computer. Since it cant verify the request. When testing localy use "http".

Comment: My guess, after some further studies, is one needs to find a workaround trough openSSL self-signed-certificates in order to test https on local environments.